# Done of 2 parts or done in 2 parts

Tags: meaning, prepositions

What is the correct version? Or what are their real meanings?

1. This process is essentially done of 2 parts
2. This process is essentially done in 2 parts.

Comment: #1 is ungrammatical. #2 is fine, though many people might prefer something more along the lines of *"This process  essentially **consists of** 2 parts"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - This process is essentially done of 2 parts
> - This process is essentially done in 2 parts.

I'm a non-native speaker of English, but both sentences look fishy to me. The first one looks outright wrong; the second is understandable but strange.

I would express the same meaning thus:

> This is essentially a two-part process.

If you want to retain [prepositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_and_postposition) in the sentence, you may wish to amend it in the following ways:

> This process essentially **consists of** 2 parts. *(kudos to FumbleFingers)*

and

> This process is essentially **divided into** 2 parts.

In the last sentence, I've changed **in** into **into**.

Comment: You're quite right that even though #2 is understandable and grammatical, it's at least *very slightly* "strange". It's not easy to say exactly *why* that should be so - maybe something to do with *essentially* implying that we're going to be told something about ***inherent/internal** attributes of the process*, rather than something more "external" about *how the process is actually implemented*. Your "suggested rephrasing" is much better/more likely than mine in the comment to the question.

Comment: Thank you, @FumbleFingers! I think that maybe the second sentence would look less jarring with the word *steps*, like this: "The process is essentially done in two **steps**".

Comment: I'd prefer *"The **procedure** is essentially **carried out** in two steps"*, but I'm not really keen on any such variants including the word *essentially*. Like I said, because that specific word primes us to expect more details on *what the process actually **is***, not *how the process is **carried out***.